# How do I prevent a user to exit using lshell?

Tags: linux, security, lshell

I am using [lshell](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell) in a linux environment.

I can create a session with this shell like

```
sudo -u dummy /usr/bin/lshell
```

but even if I add this line to the config file

```
forbidden       : [';', '&', '|','`','>','<', '$(', '${', 'exit']
```

dummy is still able to exit the shell.

Is there any way to lock dummy into his lshell session, blocking commands such as "exit" and blocking ctrl+C using lshell?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Perhaps better to just make lshell be the login shell for these users, then no need for sudo and they can't escape it.

Comment: I need to create an ajaxterm instance for localhost, but limited, since I am exposing my localhost session via web. Ajaxterm creates a session using ttycontrol.py, which takes the command line as argument

Answer (score 1):

oh, how fool I am :-)

I could just edit

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lshell.py
```

and comment

```
    #if self.g_cmd in ['quit', 'exit', 'EOF']:
    #    self.log.error('Exited')
    #    if self.g_cmd == 'EOF':
    #        self.stdout.write('\n')
    #    sys.exit(0)
```

:-)